# Solving the system $\tan x+\sin y+\sin z=3x$, $\sin x+\tan y+\sin z=3y$, $\sin x+\sin y+\tan z=3z$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x,y,z\in (0,\frac{\pi}2 )$, find all solutions to:
$$\begin{cases} \tan x+\sin y+\sin z=3x \\
\sin x+\tan y+\sin z=3y \\
\sin x+\sin y+\tan z=3z\end{cases}$$
This question was deleted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747782/

My solution.

Let $f(x)=\tan{x}+2\sin{x}-3x$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}+2\cos{x}-3\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\cdot(\cos{x})^2}-3=0,$$
which says that $f$ increases.

Thus, $$f(x)>f(0)=0$$ and
$$3\sum_{cyc}x=\sum_{cyc}(\tan{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z})=\sum_{cyc}(\tan{x}+2\sin{y})>3\sum_{cyc}x,$$
which is impossible.

Id est, our system has no solutions $(x,y,z)$, where $\{x,y,z\}\subset\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$

Is there some alternative solution for this system?

Comment: I spent a bit of time trying the following, and I think it might work. Let $c\approx 0.527538$ be the first positive root of $\tan(x)+1=3x$. Consider the plane through $(0,0,0),(c,\pi/2,0),(c,0,\pi/2)$; I claim the first equation gives an implicit surface that lies underneath this plane (this could probably be proved using the Implicit Function Theorem). Similarly for the second equation, and the third lies above the plane through $(0,0,0),(0,\pi/2,c),(\pi/2,0,c)$ But the three planes have no intersection except the origin.

Answer (score 3):

For $0 < \alpha < \pi/2$ is
$$
 \sin(\alpha) > \alpha - \frac{\alpha^3}{6}
\, , \,  \tan(\alpha) > \alpha + \frac{\alpha^3}{3} \, ,
$$
both estimates follow easily from Taylor's formula.

Using this with $\alpha = x, y, z$ in the equation system we get
$$
 3x > x+\frac{x^3}{3} +y- \frac{y^3}{6}+z- \frac{y^3}{6} \\
 3y > x-\frac{x^3}{6} +y+ \frac{y^3}{3}+z- \frac{y^3}{6} \\
 3z > x-\frac{x^3}{6} +y- \frac{y^3}{6}+z+ \frac{y^3}{3} 
$$
and adding these inequalites gives
$$
 3(x+y+z) > 3(x+y+z) \, .
$$
So there is no solution with $x, y, z \in (0, \pi/2)$.